# Anonymous struct as a return type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, return-type, function-declaration

The following code [compiles fine with *vc++ 19.00.23506*](http://rextester.com/GMUP11493) (flags: `/Wall /WX /Za`) and with *vc++ 19.10.25109.0* (flags: `/Wall /WX /Za /permissive-`, this can be checked at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net), but [doesn't compile with *clang 3.8.0* and *g++ 6.3.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f77956bb0e2138d) (flags: `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`). Is it a bug in *vc++* and does the standard prohibit such constructions?

```
struct
{
}
foo()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC appears wrong:

> **[dcl.fct]/9** Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types...

Comment: Though you can obtain an identical result in C++14 by using `auto` return types: `auto foo() { struct {} a; return a; }`

Comment: Thank you! More exact reference: **8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]**, paragraph 6 (C++03), paragraph 9 (C++11), paragraph 11 (C++14).

Answer (score 2):

You can return anonymous type, but you have to define it inside the function:

```
auto foo()
{
    struct {} s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you. The title of the question describes the problem not exactly.

Comment: Anonymous `struct` was chosen only to have the shortest MCE.

Comment: This does not work unless the function is defined where it is declared. OP's syntax would be great where declaration and definition are in separate files.